# Sails js - Locales

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I've created a custom service using sails js,which supports Internationalization.The translation json files are located in config/locales directory.How will I use these json files on client side javascript to support translations for the texts on client side javascript code.

```
config/locales/de.json

{
"": "Einen schoenen Tag noch!",
"at": "um",
"In": "In",
"ago": "Vor"
}
```

and the texts that that must be translated in the javascript file as

```
function error()
{
var msg = "text to be translated";
openMsgDialog(msg, true);
return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) ?

Comment: yeah,but its not working on the client side js. Any other alternative?

Comment: [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next) or any other `i18n-${your_framework}` libraries, depends on what you are currently using?

Comment: I'm currently using  light-weight `i18n-node-2` , which is built-in support by sails.js

Comment: [sails suggests you to use another library for client](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/internationalization#?what-about-i-18-n-on-the-client) so maybe just pick another one you like that can load those locale config?

Answer (score 1):

Sails.js only covers the server i18n, and it [suggests you to use another library for client](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/internationalization#?what-about-i-18-n-on-the-client).

You can check if [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) suits your need.